# JavaScript: Select an element to a div and update styling

Tags: javascript

I need to add styling to a DIV element using JavaScript. I have the following DIV in my document:

```
<div class="RnEpo Yx5HN   " role="presentation">
```

The script that I have tried is:

```
WebElement = document.querySelectorAll("div[class='RnEpo Yx5HN ']");
WebElement.style='height: 10000px;'
WebElement.setAttribute("height = 1000px;");
```

I want to achieve the same styling as this CSS:

```
.RnEpo Yx5HN   
{
    height: 100000px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `querySelectorAll`? And why are you mixing CSS code with JS code? (hell, that _might_ be legal depending on the build system and framework you're using, but without telling us more, [we have no way of knowing whether this is perfectly fine, or completely broken code that'll never run](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Simplicity, there are other ways to do it.

Comment: No: why are you using `querySelector**All**` instead of `querySelector`? The function you're using is [a function that returns an Array-like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead of the single element you're clearly trying to retrieve.

Comment: Haha, man i've just been trying the solutions that have presented themselves to me. This is all web based (Google Chrome).

Comment: There is only one element with that div..

Comment: Right, so use `querySelector`, and use a normal class based selector (`"div.RnEpo.Yx5HN"`), and definitely don't put CSS in your JS file, because CSS is not JS code in the slightest and will cause the JS interpreter to throw an error and terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you require, first replace `querySelectorAll()` with [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) seeing that your only need to select [the first matching element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Return_value).

Consider also revising your selector from `div[class='RnEpo Yx5HN ']` to a more robust selector in the form of `div.RnEpo.Yx5HN` which is to say:

> Select div elements that have classes any ordering of class RnEpo and Yx5HN

Lastly, revise the way that you're applying the inline style so that the `height` attribute is directly specified on the WebElement `style` object.

These changes make the call to `setAttribute()` redundant. Note also that; `setAttribute()` [takes two arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute#Syntax), and the DIV element does not have a native `height` attribute.

Here's a working snippet showing this in action:

```js
/* Use querySelector() to select first matching element and use dot notation syntax to select div with both classes */
const WebElement = document.querySelector("div.RnEpo.Yx5HN");

/* Apply inline style, avoid invalid setAttribute call */
WebElement.style.height = `10000px;'
```

```html
<div class="RnEpo Yx5HN" role="presentation">
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution I will give you a check as soon as I can!!

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans totally blind to that - very good point. Have updated answer. Thanks for the feedback :)